# Change IIS website folder using web deployment setup

Tags: c#, web-deployment

I am deployment a website using web deployment setup in .Net 4.0, it deploys the website in the inetpub folder located in the C drive, but my concern is that I want the website to some different folder using setup, is it possible to deploy the website to different location ??

Answer (score 0):

Not directly during deployment. The actual location of the Web site in IIS is defined through the IIS configuration.

To change this interactively:

In Windows Explorer, right-click on the "My Computer" icon, choose Manage.

Expand the "Services and Application" node, select "Internet Information Services".

You should then be able to select the list of sites on your PC:

[image]

Click on the "Basic Settings..." button to change the location:

[image]

---

You can also do this programatically through WMI, as explained here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/helloworld/archive/2009/05/29/how-to-programmatically-modify-the-iis-virtual-directory.aspx

or through MSBuild with the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I want to do it in the web deployment setup for the particular project. I guess your configuration will change the location of all websites in the IIS, secondly I want to do it through code in web deployment setup..

Comment: No, the path is configured for each Web site seperately. My example is for the "Default Web site", each Web site in IIS has its own physical path associated with it. As I mentioned, you can't change the location of a Web site  through Web deployment but you can do it through WMI or MSBuild.